# react-dom.development.js:26086 Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element. completely different code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

i'm making a react and django app and got stuck at this, I've tried everything, i even deleted my project and created a new one but nothing seems to be working, when i navigate to the files in devtools the code is completely different from mine, idk why they are so different the app file is completely diff to my file is app.jsx but in the devtools it imports app.js and the content is different to.

[[image: this is my actual index.js code]this is my actual index.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NZiq.png)
[[image: this is the index.js from the devtools]this is the index.js from the devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtEWv.png)

this is my webpack.config.js, i don't think this ha any issues:-

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/Main'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
        },
    })
],
};
```